Error When Attempting Updating to Ubuntu 24
I've tried twice to update to Ubuntu 24 and it's failing with an obscure message that doesn't point me in any direction to resolve. How should I troubleshoot and resolve this? I am using a Framework laptop running Ubuntu 23.10.


At what point in the upgrade did it fail?  What did a network check reveal (bad connection, noisy neighbors on your channel, etc...)?
